# Insert VBA sub into Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good day,

I am using Excel 2013 and I would like to hide and unhide my Sheets as I work with them. I spent some time Googling around and found plenty of ancient posts on forums about adding VBA to modules, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

On a main page where I spend most of my time using data, I have a button that shows a UserForm with a list of sheets in a ListBox. I choose the Sheet from the ListBox, hit OK, and it runs the following;

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()  
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(JobListBox.value).Visible = xlSheetVisible  
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(JobListBox.value).Activate  
    Unload Me  
End Sub
```

I would like it so when I have my new sheets created via VBA, I can populate the sheet with the following subroutine;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()  
    Me.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden  
End Sub
```

If anyone can let me know how I can make a Subroutine to insert this code into my sheets, I would greatly appreciate it.

PS: My fallback method is to, of course, just copy/paste the code manually... But I would prefer to automate it if possible.

Comment: I really like this idea that you are doing.  I think I might incorporate it into some of my projects.  Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Happy New Year!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding the same code to each sheet, since they are all inside the workbook and you are really trying to execute a hide once any sheet in the workbook is deactivated, put this in the code for ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

You might be able to use more workbook events with your type of project.

[Here is a list of the workbook events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook_events.aspx).

If you want to exclude your main page from this, you can modify this by adding an IF statement:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    IF Sh.Name <> "Main" Then
        Sh.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
End Sub
```

The main line of thinking being that if you have to put the same code into more than one object, let alone ALL of them, you are repeating yourself.

Check out the concept of DRY, or "Don't Repeat Yourself", unless you like it WET, "We Enjoy Typing". or "Write Everything Twice".  Even if it's just going to be created programmatically, a chunk of code shouldn't have to exist in all your sheets exactly the same when you can have one piece of code have an incoming argument that is a worksheet.

This way, if you have to make a change to its behavior, you do it once.  It's easily testable and less to keep track of or modify later.

So if you find yourself having to use the same code over and over, look to the parent object and try to find a way to pass the changing object or variable through as an argument to a singular piece of code, or module.

Also, **this is probably why you aren't finding any results** on inserting the same code into every sheet.  It's not a good practice

[Article on DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: With this code I would also add in a simple message box with a yes/no option, asking the user if they want to deactivate page so that if the user needs to keep several pages open, they can click back and forth without having to constantly open and reopen those pages.

Comment: @ThomasBeckSutton, It's a good idea.  I think this user happens to want slick operation and knows he's hiding them, or he wouldn't be using xlSheetVeryHidden.  I actually almost included that very feature with a note to comment it out if desired.  I've found though that including much more than the OP desires causes it to over-complicate the initial answer and loses the focus of the simplicity of it.  Your comment is most welcome though.

Comment: As at least one sheet needs to remain visible, the version which keeps the main sheet visible looks like the one to go with

Comment: Correct, it wouldn't let you hide all the sheets, there would be an error, "Unable to set the Visible property of the Worksheet class" on the last one.

Comment: @peege, I definitely get what you are saying and totally agree. I was just starting to picture the different uses of such a code and what I could do with it. Definitely very handy.

Comment: Thanks @peege! This is perfect for my purpose and I appreciate the advice on Best Practices and the warm welcome as well.

I hope your start to the New Year has been just as good as mine and all the best for the rest of it.